# Anonymous classes

Tags: c++, abstract-class, anonymous-class

In Java, it's common to write the following (e.g. for event handling) in order to make use of the template method pattern:

```
abstract class SomeAbstractClass {
    public abstract void SomeFunction ();
}

//...

SomeAbstractClass obj = new SomeAbstractClass () {
    public void SomeFunction () { /* implementation */ }
};
```

In C++, the following compiles:

```
class SomeAbstractClass {
    virtual void SomeFunction () = 0;
};

// ...

SomeAbstractClass * obj = new ( class : public SomeAbstractClass {
    virtual void SomeFunction () { /* implementation */ }
});
```

Why don't people do this usually?

Comment: What compiler accepts that?

Comment: Java's need to resort to them is bad enough. As for C++, using `new` is a big mistake. As well, no one does this because apart from the illegality, C++ offers far superior ways of passing functions to other functions.

Comment: @Mat : g++ --pedantic --std=c++0x, version 4.6.3

Comment: Fails with 4.7 and up, and clang++. "error: types may not be defined in a new-expression"

Comment: Seems to be this: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2012-01/msg00345.html

Answer (score 1):

Three problems i think occurs with anonymous class

- You cannot write a constructor as class doesn't have a name.
- initializer list inheritance is not allowed.
- capturing value is also difficult, final variable are accessible only.